# single requirement in parsley error message %s1

Tags: parsley.js

Hi I have a custom validator with 2 requirements(arguments/paramaters) in parsley.js

For the error message I only want to display one of the requirements but I cannot work out how

```
        messages: {en: 'You must choose at least one language with %s'},
```

I thought %s1 or %s0 might work but they don't

%s results in this message:

> You must choose at least one language as [native,enrolment_form_new_instruction_languages_proficiency]

but I just want

> You must choose at least one language as native

here is my full validator in case that helps you answer:

```
  Parsley.addValidator('oneChildEquals', {
    requirementType: ['string', 'string'],
    validateString: function(_value, requirement, requirement2, instance) {
      var $inputs = $(instance.element).find("select.language-proficiency");
      var valid = false;
      $inputs.each(function(i){
        if($(this).val() == requirement){
          valid = true; // one input has the target value (requirement2)
          return false; //break out of the loop
        }
      });
      // no input has the target value (requirement2)
      return valid;
    },
    messages: {en: 'You must choose at least one language with %s'},
  });
```

Comment: That's a bug. `window.Parsley.formatMessage` is quite basic. PR/sponsorship welcome!

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune i wrote an answer.. if you like I can try to do a PR see answer below.

Comment: Looks like a good start. Ideally `format` would receive an array for the requirements. A PR would need tests too

Comment: ok yes @Marc-AndréLafortune that would be much better.. I'll see how I go ..

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution, probably could be improved, but I don't even know if I need this now. Anyway in case anyone else does, you can just add this code:

```
      if(typeof(string) === 'string' && typeof(parameters) === 'string' && parameters.match(/^\[.*\]$/) && string.match(/\%s\d/)){

        //parameters are an array of values and string is trying to access them individually with %s1 to get first etc
        var paramsArray = parameters.slice(1, parameters.length-1).split(',');
        var interpolations = string.match(/\%s\d/g);
        for(var j = 0; j < interpolations.length ; j++){
          var interpolation = interpolations[j];
          var number = parseInt(interpolation.replace("%s", ''));

          if(isNaN(number)){
            string = string.split(interpolation).join(interpolation + '[not a valid interpolation]');
          }else {
            var val = paramsArray[number-1];
            if(typeof(val) === 'undefined'){
              val = interpolation + '[not a valid interpolation]';
            }
            string = string.split(interpolation).join(val);
          }
        }

        return string
      }
```

after this code in the source

```
    formatMessage: function formatMessage(string, parameters) {
      if ('object' === _typeof(parameters)) {
        for (var i in parameters) {
          string = this.formatMessage(string, parameters[i]);
        }

        return string;
      }
```

and before

```
      return 'string' === typeof string ? string.replace(/%s/i, parameters) : '';
```

Then it supports things like

```
      Parsley.addValidator('testParsley', {
        requirementType: ['string','string'],
        validateString: function(_value, requirement, requirement2) {
            return (_value === requirement || _value === requirement2);
          },
        messages: {en: 'test parsley this field must equal %s1 or %s2'}
      });
```